# Why are my Li's items not being checked? REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The 'checked' value on my list is not changing, i don't know why that is

I'm making a toDo app

My State Values:

```
 const [newItem, setNewItem] = useState("");
 const [toDos, setToDos] = useState([]);
```

**My function**

```
  function toggleToDo(id, completed) {
    setToDos((currentTodo) => {
      return currentTodo.map((todo) => {
        if (todo.id === id) {
          return { ...todo, completed};
        }
        return todo;
      });
    });
  }
```

**My List**

```
<ul className="list">
        {toDos.map((toDo) => {
          const { id, title, completed } = toDo;
          return (
            <li key={id}>
              <label htmlFor="">
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  checked={completed}
                  onChange={(e) => toggleToDo(id, e.target.checked)}
                />
                {title}
              </label>
              <button className="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
```

i am expecting the 'e.target.checked' to change when the function toggleToDo is called

Comment: use `onChange={(e) => toggleToDo(id, !completed)}` instead

Comment: didn't work sadly

Comment: Please include a [mre] if you can, the example code in your question appears to work when I test it. Are you clicking the checkbox itself, or the label? The label won't work as you have an empty `htmlFor=""`, but everything else should work. (This is assuming the data in `toDos` has all the expected properties, which could be another potential problem)

Comment: this was the issue indeed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**My label `<label htmlFor="">` was not linked thus my functionality was not working**

Answer (score -1):

The `checked` attribute does not indicate whether this checkbox is currently checked: if the checkbox's state is changed, this content attribute does not reflect the change.

The `value` attribute is the one that changes when the checkbox state changes.

(see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/checkbox#additional_attributes)

Comment: This directly contradicts the [React documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/input#my-checkbox-doesnt-update-when-i-click-on-it), which says: "You need to read e.target.checked rather than e.target.value for checkboxes."

Comment: so that is not the issue, then what can it be?

Comment: You're quoting the description of the `checked` **attribute** (which corresponds to `.defaultChecked` indeed), but what is relevant is the [documentation of the `checked` DOM **property**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#instance_properties_that_apply_only_to_elements_of_type_checkbox_or_radio)